# associatedtype with tableview cell

Tags: ios, generics, swift3, associated-types

I have tableview cell (`OrderMasterCell`) inside tablview cell (NESTED TABLEVIEW)

`OrderMasterCell` is been reuse in multiple view controller

Let's say ViewController1 has tableview and in tableview cell (VC1Cell) one tableview which has cell  `OrderMasterCell` (nested tableivew)

Let's say ViewController2 has tableview and in tableview cell (VC2Cell) one tableview which has cell  `OrderMasterCell` (nested tableivew)

I want custom delegate that passes  `didSelectRow`  delegate of  `OrderMasterCell` to `VC1Cell`. or `VC2Cell`

with that delegate I want to Pass Cell either VC1 or VC2 as parameter 
For that I have created Following

```
@objc protocol  OrderSubItemTableDelegate:class {
     associatedtype cellType // cell type either vc1 or vc2
     @objc optional func tableViewDidSelectRowAt(object:cellType)
}
```

and when I tried to create

```
class VC1Cell: UITableViewCell,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
      weak var delegate:OrderSubItemTableDelegate?

  }
```

It is throwing compile time error

> Protocol 'OrderSubItemTableDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

**CLEAR QUESTION**

How to create property of protocol which has  `associatedtype` ? 
like  `weak var delegate:OrderSubItemTableDelegate?`

If any one can help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You confirming protocol in wrong way.

```
 protocol  OrderSubItemTableDelegate {

     associatedtype cellType // cell type either vc1 or vc2

     static func tableViewDidSelectRowAt(object: cellType)
}

class VCCell1: UITableViewCell ,OrderSubItemTableDelegate {

    typealias cellType = VCCell1

    static func tableViewDidSelectRowAt(object: VCCell1) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Piyush Thanks for replay. But how can I confirm to that delegate. for that I need   some thing like     `weak var delegate:OrderSubItemTableDelegate?` 
and later i can use delegate = self  But it shows error

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya That is not necessary. you are telling the OBJC way of confirming protocol in swift its easy as shown in example. Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya getting?

Comment: Suppose I have a method in protocol  `tableViewDidSelectRowAt` How can i call that method  ?

Comment: I think you are not getting my point  From other class how can I call `tableViewDidSelectRowAt` Method ? . What you have shown is correct. You have define delegate and implemented in VCCell1. But from other class event I want to call function which is in protocol.

Comment: For that i need to create  `weak var delegate:OrderSubItemTableDelegate` and then call like this  `delegate. tableViewDidSelectRowAtI(cell)`

Comment: Now you have changed your question buddy. Describe you whole scenario again what you have done and what you want and from where.

Comment: you want to call `didSelectRowAt indexPath` from TableviewController to TableviewCell?

Comment: Nope I didn't change question. But see I have two VC , VC1 and VC2 both have tableview . In both tableview's cell There is another tableview. So I want child tableview didSelect -> Parent Tableview Did select

Comment: Therefore I have created protocol with associated type to pass data from child tableview cell -> Parent tableview cell. I used associated to identify it is VC1 cell or VC2 cell

Comment: However I have solved issue with type of `TableviewCell` instead of associated type still I want solution with associated type. Thanks for your efforts